# Confusion with the term 'Area bounded by the curves'

Tags: calculus, integration, terminology, area

**So I have a question:**

> Let $f(x) = \sqrt{\tan x}$ . Show that area bounded by $y = f(x)$, $y = f(c)$, $x = 0$ and $x = a$,  $0<c<a<\frac{\pi}{2}$ is minimum when $c=\frac{a}{2}$.

I have a problem in identifying the region of area bounded.
I thought and solved using this region:

> [image]

But the solution has considered the following region:

> [image]

**Note:**
For simplicity sake, I have considered $c=\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $a=\frac{\pi}{3}$ in this graph.

I am confused regarding the term **area bounded by the curves**. How do I find this region. often times I consider the wrong regions. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The yellow shaded region is the "area under the curve", bounded by a curve ($f(x)$ in this case) and the $x$-axis.

Comment: I suggest you reread the question to find the four curves that bound the region.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 what do you exactly mean by 'bound'?

Comment: If $R$ is they region “bounded by” the four given curves then the four given curves are supposed to form the boundary of the region $R$. You could think of $R$ as the region enclosed by or trapped inside the four given curves. You can’t escape the region $R$ without crossing one of the boundary curves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your proposed region has part of its boundary determined by $y=0$ (the $x$-axis), near the bottom left. This observation shows that the region you drew isn't the intended one; all pieces of boundary of the region should be parts of one of the given equations.

(Since this is about communication and not strictly about math, it's perhaps worth adding that the onus is on the writer to make sure they don't put us in a situation where the description has extraneous information or is otherwise ambiguous; and then we trust that the writer wrote the best possible description and interpret it accordingly. A writer can also write "to the left/right of" or "above/below" to help clarify instead of just "bounded by".)

Comment: So it should not share any boundary with any curve that has not been given/to us but say it shares boundary with only 3 curves out of 4 given, is this still allowed?

Comment: Well...in practice, we try to avoid that. If I say "bounded by the curves $x^2 + y^2 = 36, x^2 + y^2 = 25,$ and $x^2  + y^2 = 1$, then I've got three concentric circles of radii 6, 5, and 1. Is the whole disk of radius 6 bounded by them? Is the annulus of radii 5 and 6? There's really no great answer to this, so I'd never use it to describe a region of integration.